# Map url with language identifier

Tags: spring-mvc

Is there a nice way to resolve locale based on the URL and in the other hand map requests without any additional requirement ?

For example

```
http://example.com/ru/news    
http://example.com/iw/news
```

and in the controller still use the standard mappings

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/news")
public class NewsController {

    // Controller methods ...    

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of an out-of-the-box solution for this, but it's easy enough to implement using a custom interceptor and some wisely chosen mappings.

Write an implementation of `HandlerInterceptor` which implements `preHandle` so that the locale string is extracted from the request URI, and then tag the request with that locale ([see the source code for](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework/spring-webmvc/2.5.3/org/springframework/web/servlet/i18n/LocaleChangeInterceptor.java) the similar `LocalChangeInterceptor`, which does a similar thing to what you need, but uses a request parameter instead of a path variable).

Then [wire it up](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-localeresolver-interceptor) using `<mvc:interceptor>` e.g.

```
<mvc:interceptors>
    <mvc:interceptor>
        <mapping path="/*"/>
        <bean class="x.y.MyInterceptor" />
    </mvc:interceptor>
</mvc:interceptors>
```

You can then loosen up the request mapping on your controller to tolerate (and ignore) the locale part of the URI:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "*/news")
public class NewsController {

    // Controller methods ...    

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could write a custom interceptor that works like [`LocaleChangeInterceptor`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-localeresolver-interceptor)

Here's a sample implementation that uses a regex pattern (most of the code is copied from `LocaleChangeInterceptor`):

```
public class CustomLocaleChangeInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

    private Pattern localePattern;

    public void setLocalePattern(final String localePattern) {
        Assert.isTrue(localePattern.matches(".*\\(.*\\).*"), "Your pattern needs to define a match group");
        this.localePattern = Pattern.compile(localePattern);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response, final Object handler)
            throws ServletException {

        final String pathTranslated = request.getPathTranslated();
        if (pathTranslated != null) {

            final Matcher matcher = localePattern.matcher(pathTranslated);
            if (matcher.find()) {
                final String newLocale = matcher.group(1);
                if (newLocale != null) {
                    final LocaleResolver localeResolver = RequestContextUtils.getLocaleResolver(request);
                    if (localeResolver == null) {
                        throw new IllegalStateException("No LocaleResolver found: not in a DispatcherServlet request?");
                    }
                    final LocaleEditor localeEditor = new LocaleEditor();
                    localeEditor.setAsText(newLocale);
                    localeResolver.setLocale(request, response, (Locale) localeEditor.getValue());
                }
            }
        }
        // Proceed in any case.
        return true;

    }

}
```

Wire it like this:

```
<bean id="localeChangeInterceptor"
      class="foo.bar.CustomLocaleChangeInterceptor">
    <property name="localePattern" value="\b([a-z]{2})\b"/>
</bean
```

Comment: I think you need to use request.servletpath() instead of  request.getPathTranslated();

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://lrkwz.github.com/URLManagedLocale/ you can simply drop the dependency in your pom file and configure the interceptor and localeresolver.